# Make negative values of numpy array positive

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have [6, -1, -3, -5]. I want to make the negative values positive, e.g. [6, 1, 3, 5]. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you so much, in advance!

Comment: `numpy.abs` should do it

Comment: On Python 2 and Python 3 you can convert any number to positive with abs().  You can convert int or float negative without numpy. Example : `print(abs(-6))` show you : 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the builtin `abs` function:

```
>>> a = np.array( [6, -1, -3, -5])
>>> a
array([ 6, -1, -3, -5])

>>> abs(a)
array([6, 1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you are like me and swear by the name of **list comprehension**, try this:

```
abs_a = [-i if i <0 else i for i in a ]
```

Where **abs_a** stands for the **absolute** value of **a**

Comment: I love list comprehension too... when I deal with lists! The question here is specifically about numpy. List comprehension are still pure python iterations. They are slower (more than 2 times even with the short example given. 100 times with more serious examples). And anyway, off topic when a numpy question is asked (your `abs_a` isn't even a ndarray).